# Django upload excel file

Tags: django, django-excel

I'm trying to load my old excel format file (xls). But I got error with empty row. How can I break loop from empty row?

```
def isNaN(num):
    return num != num

wb = pd.ExcelFile(file)
first_sheet = wb.sheet_names[0]
ws = wb.parse(first_sheet, header=5)

for row in ws.itertuples():
      if isNaN(row[11]):                
            break
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers'

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: I'm using xlrd.

Comment: I just noticed that you have very weird statement `return num != num` in isNan function. It will always return False.